# Automatically generate an address for a token in the ERC20 and TRC20 network

Tags: erc-20, exchanges, usdt

How to create USDT TRC20 and ERC20 addresses for my wallet automatically via an api.
I need to create USDT TRC20 and ERC20 addresses for a small exchange so that users can deposit their tokens, an address must be unique for each deposit transaction. However I can't find a documentation on a wallet that allows to do this.
Do you have a solution for me?
I use TRUST wallet. If Trust wallet is not suitable for this kind of transaction. What do you suggest?

Comment: I have not yet mastered the language of solidity and the writing of intelligent contracts. I'm looking for methods based on pre-existing tools and if possible opensource that I can use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Metamask or `truffle-hd-wallet-provider` for creating address.You can create 'n' no of address

Comment: can I generate addresses by api with metamask?My goal is to automatically generate a different address for a wallet to track user deposits

Comment: you can use of `truffle-hd-wallet-provider` which will generate different address .NPM package @truffle/hdwallet-provider is available

Comment: Thank you, I am currently reading the documentation of this library. 
Do you know if a similar tool exists for the tron network with TRC20 tokens?

Comment: you can check `tron-wallet-hd` npm package for creating address in tron network
//accept ans if satisfied